# How to create a router-like configuration page on Raspberry PI?

Tags: web-development, node.js, networking, routing

We have a Raspberry PI (with `raspbian OS`) that runs some application, this application uses a local configuration file that contains some data like username, password, server url etc. We will provide raspberry pis (with the software installed) to users, they will have to connect them to their local network. We want to provide a way for users to change the configuration file. The solution so far is to create a local configuration web page (similar to the ones routers usually have), so the users can access this web page from their LAN and change all necessary configuration data.

What will be good solutions to do that? So far I have an idea to run a local web server on the Raspberry PI, that will run some front end web page with the UI, it will be communicating to a local back end application (Node.js as an option) that in turn will be modifying a configuration file. Are there any caveats for this solution? Are there any better/easier solutions to achieve that?
Also I would like to know how this is usually done on routers?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Questions like this are difficult to answer authoritatively, because you haven't stated your specific criteria.  Do you want the smallest memory footprint?  Most secure?  Easiest to install? I suggest you do a bit of research; this looks like a good starting point: https://www.google.com/search?q=web+server+on+raspbian

Comment: @RobertHarvey,  maybe you didn't get my question right. I'm not interested on how to create a website on raspberry pi (what languages, and web server to use, etc.), I can figure it out on my own, but rather what is a general approach for doing that on routers and can I mimic it on raspberry pi? So if a general approach is indeed to have a local back-end api that communicates to a local front-end web page, and all of that runs on a local web server, that's all I want to know. But maybe there some other architectural approaches that I'm missing?

Comment: The way you create a web page on a router is no different than the way you create one anywhere else. The specific approach you take will be based on your specific requirements and your hardware constraints, just as it would be anywhere else.